# Apache Session data/ cookies on Ionic/Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, cordova, session, cookies, ionic-framework

there.

I have my app's authentication running over an IFrame (it reuses an already functional structure shared by other systems based on web browser and it's MUST BE done this way). The iframe works just fine on all the enviroments (Android and iOS, emulators and devices), so we are good with it running that way.

**My problem is:** on the web systems, the auth process sends back an apache's session/cookie which tells the browser that a user is already authenticated and all other systems that shares the same auth protocol just knows the users are good to go without another 'sign in' process. When the user closes the browser, those session/cookies are cleared and when another window tries to access our system again, a new sign in form is presented to use make a new login. I need to reproduce this "cleaning" on my app but I don't know what, exactly, to clean.

I've already try the cache clearing methods available but nothing seems to do the trick I need.

Any clues?

**PS:** If I go to the device's seetings and clear all the app's data from there, I can make it work but is not a good way from the UX's perspective.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are asking? It sounds like you are asking how to reproduce cookies expiring?

Comment: @varlogtim It's something like that I need. Apache Session data /cookiea cleaning/expiring for the Ionic/Cordova and iframe context.